# MySQL mass INNER JOIN queries cause slow response

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, query-performance, entity-attribute-value

I've read the others related questions but mine is unique because of it's structure.

My App is storing about 10,000+ users with profiles defined by many parameters (gender, weight, height, hair color, eye color, dancing skills... and so on, about 100 attributes, lets say).

The application construct a **Filter Form** with these attributes. User is filtering database using this form so constructs a Query with many sub-queries, one for each filter used.

The problem is that using more than 8-9 filters, the engine will crash into a very long response (I had to kill the process after 30m of waiting).

So, this is the structure of Database

**Table def_attributes**  (here are the attributes definitions)

- id ---> uses as attr_id in values table

**Table utilizatori**  (users definitions, only column activ is used now)

- id        ---> is named user_id in rest of tables
- activ     ---> is 1 if user is active and will be displayed (column indexed)

**Table val_atribute**  (storing the values of attributes for each user)

- attr_id ---> the attrID of a filter **(column indexed)**
- attr_value ---> value of the attribute
- user_id    **(column indexed)**

---

For example, here is a query constructed by the Filtering form, that lags out:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Q1.user_id
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT val_atribute.user_id
        FROM   val_atribute
        WHERE  attr_id = 45
               AND attr_value IN ( 'Actor', 'Actor Amator' )) Q1
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT val_atribute.user_id
                   FROM   val_atribute
                   WHERE  attr_id = 46
                          AND Floor(Datediff(Curdate(), attr_value) / 365) >= '20') Q2
               ON Q1.user_id = Q2.user_id
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT val_atribute.user_id
                   FROM   val_atribute
                   WHERE  attr_id = 46
                          AND Floor(Datediff(Curdate(), attr_value) / 365) <= '50') Q3
               ON Q2.user_id = Q3.user_id
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT val_atribute.user_id
                   FROM   val_atribute
                   WHERE  attr_id = 47
                          AND attr_value IN ( 'feminin', 'masculin' )) Q4
               ON Q3.user_id = Q4.user_id
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT val_atribute.user_id
                   FROM   val_atribute
                   WHERE  attr_id = 102
                          AND attr_value IN ( 'African', 'Asiatic', 'Caucazian', 'Metis' )) Q5
               ON Q4.user_id = Q5.user_id
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT val_atribute.user_id
                   FROM   val_atribute
                   WHERE  attr_id = 103
                          AND attr_value >= 1) Q6
               ON Q5.user_id = Q6.user_id
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT val_atribute.user_id
                   FROM   val_atribute
                   WHERE  attr_id = 103
                          AND attr_value <= 200) Q7
               ON Q6.user_id = Q7.user_id
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT val_atribute.user_id
                   FROM   val_atribute
                   WHERE  attr_id = 104
                          AND attr_value >= 10) Q8
               ON Q7.user_id = Q8.user_id
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT val_atribute.user_id
                   FROM   val_atribute
                   WHERE  attr_id = 104
                          AND attr_value <= 150) Q9
               ON Q8.user_id = Q9.user_id
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT val_atribute.user_id
                   FROM   val_atribute
                   WHERE  attr_id = 107
                          AND attr_value IN ( 'Albastri', 'Caprui', 'Heterocrom', 'Verzi' )) Q10
               ON Q9.user_id = Q10.user_id
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT val_atribute.user_id
                   FROM   val_atribute
                   WHERE  attr_id = 108
                          AND attr_value IN ( 'Blond', 'Brunet', 'Castaniu', 'Roscat', 'Saten' )) Q11
               ON Q10.user_id = Q11.user_id
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT val_atribute.user_id
                   FROM   val_atribute
                   WHERE  attr_id = 109
                          AND attr_value IN ( 'Calvitie', 'Lung', 'Mediu', 'Scurt', 'Zero' )) Q12
               ON Q11.user_id = Q12.user_id
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT utilizatori.id
                   FROM   utilizatori
                   WHERE  activ = 1) Q13
               ON Q12.user_id = Q13.id
GROUP  BY user_id
```

---

Q2 is calculating AGE becuase weonly have attribute [Date of birth] and filter Q2 wants age > 20.

The last Query (here Q13) is always mathing active user from Table utilizatori.

I think is a problem with cartesian progression but
**Question:**  how can I remake the query to make it way more faster?
Thank you very much!

**Edit / Problem solved:**

Following Gordon Linoff's great help, I've constructed the correct query, using same filters:

`SELECT u.id
FROM   utilizatori u
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   val_atribute va
               WHERE  va.user_id = u.id
                      AND va.attr_id = 45
                      AND attr_value IN ( 'Actor', 'Actor Amator' ))
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   val_atribute va
                   WHERE  va.user_id = u.id
                          AND va.attr_id = 46
                          AND Floor(Datediff(Curdate(), attr_value) / 365) >= 20)
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   val_atribute va
                   WHERE  va.user_id = u.id
                          AND va.attr_id = 46
                          AND Floor(Datediff(Curdate(), attr_value) / 365) <= 50)
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   val_atribute va
                   WHERE  va.user_id = u.id
                          AND va.attr_id = 47
                          AND attr_value IN ( 'feminin', 'masculin' ))
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   val_atribute va
                   WHERE  va.user_id = u.id
                          AND va.attr_id = 102
                          AND attr_value IN ( 'African', 'Asiatic', 'Caucazian', 'Metis' ))
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   val_atribute va
                   WHERE  va.user_id = u.id
                          AND va.attr_id = 103
                          AND attr_value >= 1)
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   val_atribute va
                   WHERE  va.user_id = u.id
                          AND va.attr_id = 103
                          AND attr_value <= 200)
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   val_atribute va
                   WHERE  va.user_id = u.id
                          AND va.attr_id = 104
                          AND attr_value >= 10)
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   val_atribute va
                   WHERE  va.user_id = u.id
                          AND va.attr_id = 104
                          AND attr_value <= 150)
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   val_atribute va
                   WHERE  va.user_id = u.id
                          AND va.attr_id = 107
                          AND attr_value IN ( 'Albastri', 'Caprui', 'Heterocrom', 'Verzi' ))
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   val_atribute va
                   WHERE  va.user_id = u.id
                          AND va.attr_id = 108
                          AND attr_value IN ( 'Blond', 'Brunet', 'Castaniu', 'Roscat', 'Saten' ))
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   val_atribute va
                   WHERE  va.user_id = u.id
                          AND va.attr_id = 109
                          AND attr_value IN ( 'Calvitie', 'Lung', 'Mediu', 'Scurt', 'Zero' ))
       AND activ = 1`

Now query takes about 0.0015 seconds to run.

Comment: What do you select, why a group by ?

Comment: I am selecting active users (user_id) in the last query, that matches 12 filters, stored for each user in table val_atribute

Comment: If @GordonLinoff's answer solved your question, then please mark it as accepted. If you have improved on the answer, then please add your [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), instead of adding it to the question. You can also [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/), but you must wait 48 hours to do so.

Comment: Check again -- 1.5ms smells like you ran the query twice and the "Query cache" was turned on.  Add `SQL_NO_CACHE` right after `SELECT`.

Comment: @Rick James you were right, using SQL_NO_CACHE Query took 0.0055 sec which is 3 times more but still its very good in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subqueries in MySQL are problematic -- and the `select distinct` makes things worse.  You are connecting the subqueries using `and`.  I would suggest constructing the same logic using `exists` instead.

So:

```
select u.*
from users u
where exists (select 1
              from val_atribute va
              where va.user_id = u.user_id and
                    va.attr_id = 45 and
                    va.attr_value in ( 'Actor', 'Actor Amator' )
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from val_atribute va
              where va.user_id = u.user_id and
                    va.attr_id = 46 and
                    Floor(Datediff(Curdate(), va.attr_value) / 365) >= 20) Q2
             ) and
      . . .
```

This version of the query can take advantage of an index on `val_attribute(user_id, attr_id, attr_value)`.  It should be much faster and have better scalability.

Comment: Thank so much! Your solution worked brilliantly! Using exact same filters, now query took 0.0015 sec.

Comment: From 30 seconds to 0.0015 second . . . That's 99.995% speed up.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant on the notoriously inefficient EAV schema design.

So far, the best solution (in this Question) involves a full table scan of `utilizatori` with many probes into the attribute table (`val_atribute`) for filtering.

For extra efficiency, `val_atribute` needs `PRIMARY KEY(user_id, attr_id)`.  No, separate indexes on those two columns is *not* as good.

For still more efficiency, you need to pull out a *small* number of *commonly* used attributes and add an index(es).  This should avoid the full table scan (10K users, plus lots of attribute lookups), decreasing it to some fraction of that.

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

Comment: It's definetly a good aproach, I see the argument and the potential of that method but since I did not see any examples for the DB structure (just a theoretical approach) i would like to ask you: The big table that we create, will store all data user/filter/values?; Will have a column for each filter/user_id/etc./ and a row for each user? Thank you.

Comment: A _few_ indexed columns, then a big JSON structure of all the "100 attributes".  The columns and indexing will be the _first_ filtering.  Then the application does the second filtering, after unpacking the JSON.  All attributes will be in the table -- 10K rows of about a dozen columns, perhaps 2KB per row.  That adds up to a "small" 20MB table.